# Magento Ajax Form Submit

Tags: magento-1.9, ajax

I have a form it's working fine on page reload but I want to load Ajax

```
<div class="onepage_login">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function emailcheck(email) {
            /*document.getElementById("myform").submit();*/
            var url = "<?php echo Mage::getUrl('/checkout/onepage/') ?>";

            new Ajax.Request(url, {
                method: 'post',
                parameters: {email: email},
                onFailure: function (response) {
                    return false;
                },
                onSuccess: function (response) {
                    response = response.responseText;
                    return false;
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
    <?php $currentUrl = $this->helper('core/url')->getCurrentUrl(); ?>
    <?php echo $this->getMessagesBlock()->getGroupedHtml() ?>
    <?php
    $email = $_POST['email'];

    if (isset($_POST['email'])) {
        $customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer');
        $customer->setWebsiteId(Mage::app()->getWebsite()->getId());
        $customer->loadByEmail($email);
    if ($customer->getId()) { ?>
        <?php /* Extensions placeholder */ ?>
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('customer.form.login.extra') ?>
        <div class="Custom_login">
            <div class="C_login">
                <form action="<?php echo Mage::geturl('customer/account/loginPost/') ?>" method="post" id="login-form"
                      class="Custom_checkout">
                    <?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('formkey'); ?>
                    <label><h1>Get started with our login flow</h1></label>

                    <div class="checkout_login_email">
                        <input type="text" name="login[username]" placeholder="Your Email ID (username)"
                               value="<?php echo $_POST['email']; ?>" id="email"
                               class="input-text required-entry validate-email check_custom_login complete_mail"
                               title="<?php echo $this->__('Email Address') ?>" readonly/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="change">
                        <div class="edit-img">
                            <a href="<?php echo Mage::getUrl('checkout/onepage'); ?>">
                                <img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/draw.png'); ?>" alt="Edit"/>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <!--  <div class="edit-txt">
                           <span> Edit </span> 
                        </div> -->

                    </div>

                    <div class="checkout_login_pss">
                        <input type="password" name="login[password]" placeholder="Password"
                               class="input-text required-entry validate-password check_custom_login_pass" id="pass"
                               title="<?php echo $this->__('Password') ?>"/>
                    </div>
                    <br/><br/>
                    <a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('customer/account/forgotpassword') ?>"
                       class="f-left"><?php echo $this->__('Forgot your password?') ?></a>

                    <div class="checkout_login_button">
                        <button type="submit" class="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Login') ?>" name="send"
                                id="send2"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Login') ?></span></span></button>
                    </div>

                    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('form.additional.info'); ?>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            //<![CDATA[
            var dataForm = new VarienForm('login-form', true);
            //]]>
        </script>
    <?php
    }
    else{
    //echo"not available";
    ?>
        <form action="<?php echo Mage::geturl('customer/account/createpost/') ?>" method="post" name="fom"
              id="form-validate">
            <h2> Please Enter Below Mentoin Details </h2>
            <?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('formkey'); ?>
            <div class="Checkout_reg">
                <ul class="form-list">
                    <div class="customer-regi">
                        <div class="field name-email">
                            <div class="input-box">
                                <input placeholder="Email Address" onblur="emailcheck(this.value);" type="email"
                                       name="email" id="email" class="input-text " required
                                       value="<?php echo $_POST['email']; ?>" readonly/>
                                <!--  <div class="change"><a href="<?php echo Mage::getUrl('checkout/onepage'); ?>"> Change </a></div> -->
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="field name-firstname">
                            <div class="input-box">
                                <input placeholder="First Name" id="fname" name="firstname" value="" title="First Name"
                                       maxlength="255" class="input-text required-entry" type="text" required>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="field name-psw">
                            <div class="input-box">
                                <input placeholder="Set New Password" type="password" pattern=".{6,20}" required
                                       title="Password should atleast 6 characters" name="password" id="password1"
                                       class="input-text required-entry validate-password" required/>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="field name-cnfpsw">
                            <div class="input-box">
                                <input placeholder="Confirm Password" type="password" minlength="6" name="confirmation"
                                       id="password2" class="input-text required-entry validate-cpassword" required/>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <button type="submit" name="continue" class="button" id="onepage-guest-register-button">
                            <span><span><?php echo $this->__('Submit') ?></span></span>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </form>
    <?php }
    }
    else{
    ?>
        <form id="myform" name="myform" method="POST">
            <label><h1>Get started with our login flow</h1></label>

            <div class="email-enter-field">
                <input placeholder="Email Address" type="email" name="email" id="email"
                       class="input-text check_custom_login" required autocomplete="on"/>
            </div>
            <a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('customer/account/forgotpassword') ?>"
               class="f-left"><?php echo $this->__('Forgot your password?') ?></a>
            <button class="button" name="submit" onclick="emailcheck();"/>
            <span><span><?php echo $this->__('Submit') ?></span></span> </button>
        </form>
    <?php }
    ?>
</div>
```

If already have account i will show this form

```
<form action="<?php echo Mage::geturl('customer/account/loginPost/')?>" method="post" id="login-form" class="Custom_checkout">

</form>
```

else New user i needs to show this form

```
<form action="<?php echo Mage::geturl('customer/account/createpost/')?>" method="post" name="fom" id="form-validate">

</form>
```

How to achieve this in Ajax i done in **js** but i want to Ajax how to do this

Answer (score 0):

You can use **protoype ajax** just add this and your `url`

```
function emailcheck(email)
{
    var url="<?php echo str_replace('index.php/','',Mage::getBaseUrl('web', true)).'test.php' ?>";

    new Ajax.Request(url, {
        method: 'post',
        parameters: {email: email},
        onFailure: function(response){
            return false;
        },
        onSuccess: function(response)
        {
            response = response.responseText;
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

create `test.php` in main folder:

```
require_once('app/Mage.php');
umask(0);
Mage::app('default');
$email = $_POST['email'];

if (isset($_POST['email'])) {
    $customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer');
    $customer->setWebsiteId(Mage::app()->getWebsite()->getId());
    $customer->loadByEmail($email);
    if ($customer->getId()) {
        echo 1;
    } else {
        echo 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: is it correct var url="<?php echo Mage::getUrl('/checkout/onepage/') ?>";

Comment: you have to add myform submit action

Comment: No ididn't create any controller just create one form and submit that's all

Comment: which url it is submitting if the same then you have to create a controller and do ajax response there.

Comment: Check my full code

Comment: create controller for check and make login and create form hidden response of controller show desire page that is solution for you.

Comment: Ok i will follow that

Comment: can you please give any example to check customer available or not in controller

Comment: added the example follow it

Comment: I need to add that phtml or controller

Comment: add it where is index.php is located add there

Comment: Sorry i am not getting

Comment: you have create new `test.php`  `yourhomepage/here`. if you don't want to create a controller.

Comment: var url="<?php echo str_replace('http://domain.com/checkout/onepage/','',Mage::getBaseUrl('web', true)).'test.php' ?>"; is it correct it still reload the page

Comment: this is not correct kindly create controller in any install module and use that

Comment: okay i will check it

Comment: Can you please check this http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/111920/submit-form-in-ajax

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a controller in magento.
2. Submit your form through ajax to that controller.
3. Return html for your form though the ajax controller and echo it on you page.